# Find a document if it's 'id' is part of another collection subdocuments

Tags: mongodb

I want to do the 'exact opposite' of a [query on nested fields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-embedded-documents/#query-on-nested-field)

- **not** `db.inventory.find( { "size.uom": "in" } )`
- **but** `db.inventory.find( { "in": "size.uom" } )`

---

In details, I have a document like this in the `enter` collection:

```
{
    "_id" : "iiED3kBWDLenD9fC4",
    "added" : ISODate("2018-04-04T20:32:49.295Z"),
    "teammember" : {
        "member" : [ 
            "JmfSvvP57LwKhRYZZ", 
            "hevxqtcxm3ftKd4ki"
        ]
    }
}
```

So if we have

```
var bobyo = enter.teammember.member;
// console.log() give [ 'JmfSvvP57LwKhRYZZ', 'hevxqtcxm3ftKd4ki' ]
```

how to perform a query in the `user` collection to find users who have as `id` one of the elements of `bobyo`  (false query, just to give the idea):

```
users.find ({"_id": "bobyo"}, {fields: {"_id": 1}})
```

to return

```
users.find ({"_id": "JmfSvvP57LwKhRYZZ"}, {fields: {"_id": 1}})

users.find ({"_id": "hevxqtcxm3ftKd4ki"}, {fields: {"_id": 1}})
```

**EDIT/SOLUTION
The solution is to use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) operator.**

Comment: I guess you can use $lookup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#use-the-in-operator-to-match-values-in-an-array) operator.

So, the query will be:

```
var bobyo = enter.teammember.member;
var selector = {_id: {$in: bobyo}};
var options = {fields: {_id: 1}};

return users.find(selector, options);
```

Found the answer (Meteor particular case) in [David Weldon blog](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes) (`Published Secrets` title).

Answer (score 0):

Try the query below

```
db.users.aggregate([
  { $lookup: {
    from: "enter",
    localField: "_id",
    foreignField: "teammember.member",
    as: "enter"
  }
}])
```

Comment: what is `abc` in `as: "abc"`?

Comment: that's just a name for the relationship. I'll change to enter